# how to enable ssh from container to Linux remote machine

Tags: ssh, rhel, docker, scp, container

we try to perform `ssh / scp` from docker container to remote LINUX redhat machine

```
ssh  remote_server
echo $?

255

ssh -vvv remote_server
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "remote_server" port 2122
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remote_server [35.3.23.12] port 2122.
debug1: connect to address 35.3.23.12 port 2122: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host remote_server port 2122: Connection refused
```

we also tried to copy `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from container to remote_server but with the same state

any suggestion how to enable `ssh / scp` from container to remote machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that /root/.ssh/config is adding port 2122 for you, which is a non-standard port for SSH.

- If that's not the port you expect, edit the config file as needed.
- If that *is* the port you expect, it's apparent that there's either something preventing access to that port (firewall) or the SSH service is not running on remote_server on port 2122.